# Swift crashes in CFRelease when leaving scope

Tags: ios, swift

I've just thrown myself into iOS development and I'm current getting a runtime error in the function CFRelease just at the end of the queryServer function (I put a comment on the line that get's highlighted) and I don't have an error if I comment out the function call to extractIPFromQuery.

The code below is taking the name of a server and returning a list of ip addresses to that server.

```
func extractIPFromQuery(query: NSArray) -> [String] {
    var addresses = [String]()

    for x in 0...query.count - 1{
        let adr = "\(query[x])"
        let adrStart = adr.startIndex.advancedBy(10)
        let adrEnd = adr.startIndex.advancedBy(18)
        let address = adr.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: adrStart, end: adrEnd))
        var final = ""

        // Convert the hex version of the address into
        // a human readable version

        for seg in 0...3{
            let start = address.startIndex.advancedBy(seg * 2)
            let end = address.startIndex.advancedBy((seg * 2) + 2)
            let hexRange = Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end)
            let hexPair = address.substringWithRange(hexRange)

            final += "\(UInt8(strtoul(hexPair, nil, 16)))"
            if(seg != 3){
                final += "."
            }
        }

        addresses.append(final)
    }
    return addresses;
}

func queryServer(hostName: String) -> [String]{
    var ips = [String]()
    if  hostName != "\0" {
        let hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, hostName).takeRetainedValue()
        while(CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, CFHostInfoType.Addresses, nil) == false){}
        ips += extractIPFromQuery(CFHostGetAddressing(hostRef, nil)!.takeRetainedValue() as NSArray)
    } // Code breaks here
    return ips
}
```

Comment: Do you pass a valid server name when calling `queryServer`?

Comment: The code does work and ips is populated with a bunch of addresses

Comment: As this crashes when leaving the `if` scope, then it means it has to do with either one of the variables used within the scope: `hostRef` or the result of `CFHostGetAddressing`.

Comment: Have also a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890533/how-can-i-get-a-real-ip-address-from-dns-query-in-swift for an easier method to convert the IP addresses to strings, using `getnameinfo()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CFHostGetAddressing` does not have "Create" or "Copy" in its name,
which means that it does not return a (+1) retained object.
Therefore you have to use `takeUnretainedValue()` to get the
value of the unmanaged reference.

For more information about these naming conventions, see "The Create Rule" and "The Get Rule"
in [Ownership Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)
in the "Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation".

Comment: Thank you and @Cristik, that have solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking ownership of the array returned by `CFHostGetAddressing`, which means `ARC` will insert a `release` call to balance the `retain` call that thinks needs to be balanced, when in fact it doesn't need to do this. You should be using `takeUnretainedValue()` instead of `takeRetainedValue()` as the name semantics of `CFHostGetAddressing` don't imply you are required to take ownership of the result.

At a basic level, the difference between `takeRetainedValue()` and `takeUnretainedValue()` is that the former will instruct ARC to insert a `release` call when the variable get's out of scope, while the latter one will not. At a semantical level, the former one tells that you want, or need to take ownership of the variable, usually meaning that there's an unbalanced `retain` call on that object, which `ARC` will balance.