# How to cast sockaddr_in to sockaddr in swift

Tags: swift, sockets, casting

I'm trying to do some network code in swift and the type checking is giving me fits.

```
var sock: CInt = ...
var rin: sockaddr_in
var rlen = socklen_t(sizeof(sockaddr_in))
var buffer: CChar[] = CChar[](count: 128, repeatedValue: 0)

let len = recvfrom(sock, &buffer, 128, 0, &rin, &rlen)
```

The compiler complains (very cryptically) at the `recvfrom` about the fact that `&rin` is a pointer to `sockaddr_in` instead of `sockaddr`. I tried various ways to convert the pointer type, but I can't seem to get this right.

If I declare it to be a `sockaddr` I can get this to compile, but then I can't look at it as a `sockaddr_in`.

Answer (score 7):

**Update** for Swift 3 and later, compare [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html):

```
var sock: CInt = 1234
var rin = sockaddr_in()
var rlen = socklen_t(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: rin))
var buffer = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: 128)

let len = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &rin) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        recvfrom(sock, &buffer, buffer.count, 0, $0, &rlen)
    }
}
```

---

***Update:*** As of Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta), initializing a C struct
has become much simpler:

```
var rin = sockaddr_in()
```

defines a `sockaddr_in` variable and initializes all elements to zero.
The conversion of a address of `sockaddr_in` to an an address of
`sockaddr` is done as follows:

```
let len = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&rin) {
    recvfrom(sock, &buffer, UInt(buffer.count), 0, UnsafeMutablePointer($0), &rlen)
}
```

---

***Old answer:*** The first problem is that the `sockaddr_in` variable has to be initialized before
its address can be passed to `recvfrom()`. Initializing complex structs in Swift
seems to be clumsy, compare

- [Swift: Pass Uninitialized C Structure to Imported C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146488/swift-pass-uninitialized-c-structure-to-imported-c-function).

Using the helper function from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24335355/1187415:

```
func initStruct<S>() -> S {
    let struct_pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<S>.alloc(1)
    let struct_memory = struct_pointer.move()
    struct_pointer.dealloc(1)
    return struct_memory
}
```

the socket address can be initialized as

```
var rin : sockaddr_in = initStruct()
```

To cast the `sockaddr_in` pointer to a `sockaddr` pointer, use `reinterpretCast()`.

```
let len = recvfrom(sock, &buffer, UInt(buffer.count), 0, reinterpretCast(&rin), &rlen)
```

Comment: Do you have a Swift 5 version for `let len = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&rin)...`? Fails due to being ambiguous.

Comment: @shallowThought: I have updated the code.

Comment: Thank you, Helpful! A little explanation would be great.