# How to cast sockaddr_in to sockaddr in swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, sockets

I saw the question here :
[cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-in-swift 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939431/how-to-cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-in-swift)

But when I try to use these code in swift 2.0, I got an error:

```
var sa = sockaddr_in()
let s =  socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)

let cn = connect(s,UnsafeMutablePointer( &sa ), sizeof(sa) )
```

> Ambiguous use of 'init'

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similarly as in the [referenced Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939431/how-to-cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-in-swift), you have to use `withUnsafePointer()`

```
var sa = sockaddr_in()
let s =  socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)

let cn = withUnsafePointer(&sa) { 
    connect(s, UnsafePointer($0), socklen_t(sizeofValue(sa)))
}
```

Note also that `sizeofValue()` must be used with an instance of
a type, and that the value must be converted to `socklen_t`
as expected by `connect()`.

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
let cn = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &sa) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        connect(s, $0, socklen_t(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: sa)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that gives "Cannot convert value of type 'inout sockaddr_in' to expected argument type 'inout _'". So, no.

Comment: @Honza: The question and answer referred to Swift 2. Pointer conversion changed considerably with Swift 3. I have added the corresponding Swift 3 code.