# EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN when reading from NSData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unsafe-pointers

I have the following class:

```
class RawDataArray {
    var data: NSData!

    init(filePath: String) {
        data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    }

    func read<T>(offset: Int) -> T {
        return UnsafePointer<T>(data.bytes + offset).memory
    }
}
```

which I use in my iOS app to read from a binary file with a custom format. For example, to read an `Int` at offset 5, I use:

`let foo = rawData.read(5) as Int`

This works in the simulator, on my iPad Air, and has passed the review for beta testing. However, my external testers have iPad 2s and 4s, and they are getting `EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN` errors.

I cannot change the structure of the input file. Is there any way to fix the `read` function to make sure the objects are built from properly aligned memory locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, reading unaligned data can fail on some architectures.
A safe method is to *copy* the bytes into a (properly aligned) variable.

So the first idea would be to write a generic function:

```
func read<T>(offset: Int) -> T {
    var value : T
    memcpy(&value, data.bytes + offset, UInt(sizeof(T)))
    return value
}
```

*However, this does not compile,* because the variable `value`
must be initialized before being used, and there is no default
constructor that can be used to initialize a complete generic
variable.

If we restrict the method to types which can be initialized with `0` then we get this:

```
func read<T : IntegerLiteralConvertible>(offset: Int) -> T {
    var value : T = 0
    memcpy(&value, data.bytes + offset, UInt(sizeof(T)))
    return value
}
```

This works for all integer and floating point types.

For the general case, one could use the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24335355/1187415:

```
func read<T>(offset: Int) -> T {
    // Allocate space:
    let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(1)
    // Copy data:
    memcpy(ptr, data.bytes + offset, UInt(sizeof(T)))
    // Retrieve the value as a new variable: 
    var item = ptr.move()
    // Free the allocated space
    ptr.dealloc(1)
    return item
}
```

Swift allows to overload functions with different return types,
therefore you can actually define *both* methods, and the compiler will
automatically choose the more restrictive one.

Comment: Many thanks for saving my weekend! I was about to start writing some awful code to shift bytes, etc.

Answer (score -2):

> FOR ALL **SWIFT** DEVELOPERS THAT READ THIS

I had a different case with the same crash type!

If your project is defined for (old?) swift version, but you link against a cocoa pod (in my case) that has a different (newer?) swift version in **build settings** - you’re going to get that **crash** even when you just trying to set a value of a public field in a regular **swift struct**.

The stack trace will tell you nothing and may show you the wrong place (CAAnimation free memory for example)

*In my case my project was in **Swift 4**, and my pod (SwiftMessages) was **Swift 4.2***

> AND **BOOM**!!!

Happy coding!

Comment: I really don't understand why 2 downvotes here.
this answer helped me, and might help others.. if the answer has any issue - please comment and explain.. I won't delete it because it might also help myself in the future..
if it didn't help you it doesn't mean you need to downvote