# getch() equivalent in Swift: read a single character from stdin without a newline

Tags: swift, terminal, stdin, ncurses, getch

I'm looking for a Swift function like [`getch()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) from C to read a single character from terminal input without requiring the user to press the return key. [`getchar()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar.html) and [`readLine()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641199-readline) are not sufficient, as they both require return.

There's a [`getch()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) function from ncurses which looked promising, but unfortunately [seems to require](https://stackoverflow.com/a/905107/12638282) taking over the display of the whole window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a while online, I landed on the following (partly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748507/listening-to-stdin-in-swift/49780011#49780011)):

```swift
import Foundation

extension FileHandle {
    func enableRawMode() -> termios {
        var raw = termios()
        tcgetattr(self.fileDescriptor, &raw)

        let original = raw
        raw.c_lflag &= ~UInt(ECHO | ICANON)
        tcsetattr(self.fileDescriptor, TCSADRAIN, &raw)
        return original
    }

    func restoreRawMode(originalTerm: termios) {
        var term = originalTerm
        tcsetattr(self.fileDescriptor, TCSADRAIN, &term)
    }
}

func getch() -> UInt8 {
    let handle = FileHandle.standardInput
    let term = handle.enableRawMode()
    defer { handle.restoreRawMode(originalTerm: term) }

    var byte: UInt8 = 0
    read(handle.fileDescriptor, &byte, 1)
    return byte
}

fputs("Press any key to continue... ", stdout)
fflush(stdout)

let x = getch()
print()
print("Got character: \(UnicodeScalar(x))")
```